# Closure as duplicate navigating in a circle

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, exact-duplicates, close-reasons

I was reviewing the close votes today when I came across this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394223/system-of-linear-equations-having-a-real-solution-has-also-a-rational-solution) , for identification purpose, lets call this $\mathbf{A}$. Someone had given it a close vote, marking it a duplicate of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390818/revisited-2-does-a-solution-in-mathbbrn-imply-a-solution-in-mathbbq), let's call this $\mathbf{B}$.
When I saw that the close vote was logical and I tried to put my own close vote, the following message showed up:

> This closure would result in the "duplicate of" navigation leading in
>   a circle.

[image]

I then realised carefully that the other question had been marked duplicate of this question only. On careful scrutiny, I found out that $\mathbf{B}$ was asked earlier, that is, on May $13$, $2013$ and $\mathbf{A}$ was asked later, that is, on May $17$, $2013$. Hence, $\mathbf{A}$ should be *rightfully closed* as a duplicate while $\mathbf{B}$ should remain open. But to add to the confusion, the same user has asked both the questions and they are even linked to each other, although the second question does not ask for a hint on the first.

What should be done with these $2$ questions? Which one should be closed and which one should be kept open?

Comment: Time does not matters a lot, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/original-post-marked-as-duplicate) for example.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/loop-of-duplicate-posts